# Is there a way to change/edit icons imported to Android Studio the same way you can edit the ones that already come pre-installed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, icons

Is it possible to use Android Studio to change the color of icons imported to Android Studio, say if I wanted to change the border of the icon that I found online the same way that you can change the color of icons that Android Studio already has using the Custom option or do most people use some other system to create their own personalized icons?

I have found some good icons online, but in a certain function for my app I have to change their borders and I need to use the same icon, just with different colored borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by drawable -> New ->Image asset [image: and then you can add the path of your image and select your custom color]

Comment: Okay, perfect thank you. And you have to use png files I was using jpg and it wasn't working. Thanks!